# Why CIColorCube does not implement on my Image?

Tags: ios, swift, core-image

I want to implement CIColorCube to my UIImage and for this I do the next:

```
var filter = CIFilter(name: "CIColorCube")
    let sourceImage = CIImage(image: UIImage(named: "some_image.png"))
    filter!.setValue(sourceImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
    filter!.setDefaults()

    var size: UInt = 64
    var floatSize = UInt(sizeof(Float))
    var cubeDataSize:size_t = Int(size * size * size * floatSize * 4)

    let colorCubeData: [Float] = [
        1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 0, 0, 1,
        0, 1, 0, 1,
        1, 1, 0, 1,
        0, 0, 1, 1,
        1, 0, 1, 1,
        0, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1
    ]
    let cubeData = NSData(bytes: colorCubeData, length: colorCubeData.count * sizeof(Float))
    let context = CIContext(options: nil)
    let outputCGImage = context.createCGImage(filter!.outputImage!, fromRect: filter!.outputImage!.extent)
    let filteredImage = UIImage(CGImage: outputCGImage)
```

and when I use this filter to my image, nothing happens. So, what I do wrong? Is it there something what I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think in the code above you are missing this:

```
filter!.setValue(cubeData, forKey: "inputCubeData")
filter!.setValue(2, forKey: "inputCubeDimension")
```